How do you configure a Telegram bot to listen to and respond to messages in a Telegram channel?
I've obtained the Telegram channel ID using IDBot, simplifying the identification process. Additionally, I've elevated a bot to admin status within the channel, granting it full administrative privileges
import telebot
from helper import TextHelper
import os
import contants
import time

bot = telebot.TeleBot(contants.BOT_ACCESS_TOKEN, parse_mode=None)
obj = TextHelper()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def send_ans(message):
    try:
        text = message.text.split(' ')[1]
        stat, filex, captionx = obj.getText(text)
        if stat == True:
            bot.send_document(message.chat.id, open(filex, 'rb'), caption=captionx, reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
            os.remove(filex)
        else:
            bot.reply_to(message, captionx)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, str(e))

def polling_wrapper():
    while True:
        try:
            bot.remove_webhook()
            bot.infinity_polling()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
            time.sleep(5)

try:
    polling_wrapper()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")


we can make use of @bot.channel_post_handler()
which will listen to channel messages and respond
